# Finding entries with similar attributes in same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table set up like this... this is greatly simplified to make the question easier to ask.

```
|id|hobby    |person |enjoyment
-------------------------------
|  |soccer   |john   |10
|  |soccer   |jake   |5
|  |baseball |john   |3
|  |baseball |nate   |5
|  |baseball |jordan |2
|  |tennis   |john   |3
|  |tennis   |nate   |7
|  |chess    |john   |10
|  |chess    |nate   |3
```

Each person has a score of how much they enjoy a particular hobby. If they don't have a record in the database for a particular hobby, we assume they don't participate.

Given 1 person, I need to know who at least participates in the most similar hobbies. In the above example, if I chose John, it should set Nate as (3) since they share 3 hobbies in common (baseball, tennis and chess), jake and jordan would both get (1)

I could do this with multiple queries of course...

```
SELECT hobbies FROM tblname WHERE person='john';

SELECT person FROM tblname WHERE hobbies='baseball'
       AND hobbies='tennis' AND hobbies='chess' AND name!='john'
```

and keep doing that but it seems INCREDIBLY inefficient.

Is there a single optimized query to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: Come on - you can do a better than this! -and there's no column in your table called `hobbies`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT something
      , COUNT(*)
   FROM hobbies john
   JOIN hobbies notjohn 
     ON notjohn.something <> john.something
    AND notjohn.some_other_thing = john.some_other_thing
  WHERE john.person = 'x' 
  GROUP 
     BY ?.?;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a solution, tho it's done with a sub query which might not be the most performant way to do it.

I think the query is self explanatory.

You count the number of rows returned where the hobbies are in the list of your hobbies.

I assumed that this would be done in some kind of loop, so I could use john in the where clauses.

```
SELECT person, COUNT(*) AS nbrMatches FROM hobbies
WHERE hobby IN 
                (SELECT hobby FROM hobbies WHERE
                person='john')
AND person <> 'john'
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY nbrMatches DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test it sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86e74/6/1

```
SELECT t_other.person, count(*)
FROM tbl as t_john, tbl as t_other
WHERE t_john.person = 'john'
  AND t_other.hobby = t_john.hobby
  AND t_other.person != 'john'
GROUP BY t_other.person;
```

Answer (score 0):

[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01579/7/0) is what I think you're looking for
already answered above.